# How to get the section number above section title (like given example)

Tags: section-titles

I wonder how I would be able to achieve this effect like the authors of this report have done with a big section number above the section title and where both the title and number are centered and with a large font size. There should also be some spacing from the section title to the following text. I would like to only have this effect on `\section` and leave the subsections as normal.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! It is actually a chapter, I suppose?

Comment: This is part of a technical report so my first guess was that it was a section but I don't know anything chapters in latex. I'm only interested in getting this look and still having my table of contents intact and if using chapters is the way achieve that I'm all ears

Comment: I asked only for consistency. Do you use the `report` class?

Comment: Excuse my ignorance I'm not that knowledgeable about the latex settings. We have `\begin{document}` so that means that we use the document class (?)

Comment: No, `begin{document}` marks the beginning of the actual document's body and the end of the premable. The document class is in the  `\documentclass` that should be in the first line of the document.

Comment: We use `\documentclass[12pt]{article}` so the `article` class

Comment: A compilable latex file begins with a preamble, which begins with `\documentclass{some class}` and ends at `begin{\document]`. The basic document cmasses are `book`, `report`, `article` and `letter`. There also document cmasses  deined in specific packages, e.g. `beamer` for presentations. The preamble contains personal macros, loadin useful packages that you may need, &c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool of choice to customise chapter, section, &c. layout is `titlesec`. This should produce a layout not so far from what you want:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
...............
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[display]{\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{\scalebox{2}{\thesection}}{3ex}{}
...............

\begin{document}

\section{Teori}

Deppa kapitel presenterar den teori varpå projektet bygger.
```

Comment: That does achieve the positioning but is how would I get an even bigger digit like in the picture where it's almost twice the size of the title? And how would I increase the spacing from the section title to the text?

Comment: I've posted a slightly modified code with `\scalebox`.The value od the scaling can  be adjusted to your needs.